# Org Export of R Code not showing results with :results output

Tags: org-babel

I seem to not be understanding something fundamental. I am not able to get R output to come through with the `:results output` header argument. Here is a reproducible example from `emacs -Q`.

Here is my simple config used with `emacs -Q`:

```
;; Install Straight -- per straight documentation
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

;; Install use-package through straight 
;; Now use-package will use straight.el to automatically install
;; missing packages if you provide :straight t:
(straight-use-package 'use-package)

; This is only needed once, near the top of the file
(eval-when-compile
  ;; Following line is not needed if use-package.el is in ~/.emacs.d
  ;; (add-to-list 'load-path "<path where use-package is installed>")
  (require 'use-package))


(straight-use-package 'org)
(straight-use-package '(org-contrib :type git :host github :repo "emacsmirror/org-contrib"))

(use-package org
         :config
    (org-babel-do-load-languages
     'org-babel-load-languages
     '((R . t)
       (emacs-lisp . t)
       (latex . t)
       (org . t)))
    (add-to-list 'org-export-backends 'org)
    )
(straight-use-package 'ess)
(use-package ess)
```

Here is my simple file I am trying to export to a Beamer PDF.

```
# -*- eval: (setq-local ess-startup-directory default-directory) -*-
#+TITLE:     foo
#+AUTHOR:    foo
#+DATE:      
#+DESCRIPTION: 
#+KEYWORDS: 
#+LANGUAGE:  en
#+BEAMER_THEME: Boadilla
#+BEAMER_HEADER: 
#+latex_class: beamer
#+latex_class_options:
#+latex_header: 
#+latex_header_extra:
#+latex_compiler: pdflatex
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:nil
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}<beamer>\vfill\centering\usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\vfill\end{frame}}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{pdfpages}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{caption}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{subcaption}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{multicol}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{amssymb}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \definecolor{links}{HTML}{4167E1}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+OPTIONS: d:(not "RELATED") ^:nil
* foo
** Slide
#+begin_src R :exports both :session "*R*" :results output
  x <- 45
  x
#+end_src
```

Here is the output of the relevant slide: notice that there should be a line saying that the output of this block is the number 45 but it only shows the code. It works if I change `:results output` to `:results value` but then its an org-formatted table which I don't want.

[image: slide that gets exported]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a recent bug that has been reported and fixed in the most recent versions of Org:

https://list.orgmode.org/877czca7oj.fsf@u-bordeaux.fr/

The problem was fixed by downlading the current head of the org git repo and loading that.